# Dealing with "null" values in python Altair tooltip's text

Tags: python, tooltip, visualization, altair

I have a pandas dataset with three columns ('Time',  'Actual Value' , 'Prediction').
I am trying to plot two lines in same figure using Altair package in python:

```
-Actual Value vs Time 

-Prediction vs Time
```

In parts of the dataset, I have null values (np.nan)  in 'Actual Price' and 'Prediction' columns.

When I add tooltips, I get 'null' as text in parts that I have np.nan:

```
Time : August 30, 2018
Actual Value : null
Prediction : 150
```

I want to change the text in the tooltip to a customize one (like: 'Not Available').

Desired output in tooltip :

```
Time : August 30, 2018
Actual Value : Not Available
Prediction : 150
```

[image]

```
data = {'Time':  pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=8, freq='M'),
            'Actual Value': [100, 150, 200, 120, 180, 150, 110, np.NaN],
            'Prediction' : [np.NaN, 140, 180, 110, 160, 140, 120, 150]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data) 

## Altair Plots 
base = alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    line1="'Actual Value'",
    line2="'Prediction'",
).properties(
    height=360,
    width = 800
)


scale = alt.Scale(domain=["Actual Value", "Prediction"], range=['blue', 'orange'])


line1 = base.mark_line(opacity=0.8,color='blue').encode(
    x=alt.X('Time:T',title='Time'),
    y=alt.Y('Actual Value:Q',axis = alt.Axis(title="Price")),
    color = alt.Color('line1:N', scale=scale, title=' '),
)

line2 = base.mark_line(color='orange').encode(
    x=alt.X('Time:T',title='Time'),
    y=alt.Y('Prediction:Q',axis = alt.Axis(title="Price")),
    color = alt.Color('line2:N',scale=scale, title=' '),
)

# Tooltip Function 

def createTooltip():
    """
        This function creates a tooltip containing the date, and prices displayed upon hover
    
    """
    hover = alt.selection_single(
        fields=["Time"],
        nearest=True,
        on="mouseover",
        empty="none",
        clear="mouseout",
    )
    tooltips = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule(strokeWidth=0.5,  color="black", strokeDash=[4,2]).encode(
        x='Time',
        opacity=alt.condition(hover, alt.value(1), alt.value(0)),
        tooltip=["Time",
                 alt.Tooltip("Actual Value:N", title='Actual Value'), 
                 alt.Tooltip("Prediction:N", title='Prediction')]
    ).add_selection(hover)
    
    
    return tooltips



tooltips =  createTooltip()
alt.layer(line1+line2, tooltips).interactive()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a [calculate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html). For example:

```python
tooltips = alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    P="isValid(datum.Prediction) ? datum.Prediction : 'Undefined'",
    A="isValid(datum['Actual Value']) ? datum['Actual Value'] : 'Undefined'"
).mark_rule(strokeWidth=0.5,  color="black", strokeDash=[4,2]).encode(
    x='Time',
    opacity=alt.condition(hover, alt.value(1), alt.value(0)),
    tooltip=["Time",
             alt.Tooltip("A:N", title='Actual Value'), 
             alt.Tooltip("P:N", title='Prediction')]
).add_selection(hover)
```