# Altair tooltip: avoid showing missing entries

Tags: python, altair

Similar to this question: [Dealing with "null" values in python Altair tooltip's text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67427923), I have missing values in some field of columns that I use for a tooltip. But rather than changing the text (default is `null` for dtype string and `0` for numeric columns), I would like to not show these lines at all in the tooltips.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data with missing values
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'y': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'c': ['a', 'b', None, 'd'],  # Example metadata column with missing values
    'd': [100, np.nan, 300, None]    # Example metadata column with missing values
})

# Create the Altair chart
alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    tooltip=['x', 'y', 'c', 'd']
)
```

This shows four lines of information in each tooltip including the missing values. What I want is, that the tooltips at data points for x= 2, 3 and 4 only have only 3 lines by skipping the missing information. Is this possible?